# same file not picked up by multiple hosts

Tags: spring-integration, sftp

I have an app hosted multiple hosts listening to single remote SFTP location. How should i make sure same file is not picked by an host which is already picked up by other? I am pretty new to spring integration. Appreciate someone can share examples

}

EDIT:
Here is my integration flow getting file from sftp and placing in local directory and performing business logic in transformer and returning file and send it to remote sftp.

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    LOGGER.debug(" Creating SFTP Session Factory -Start");
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(sftpHost);
    factory.setUser(sftpUser);
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setPassword(sftpPassword);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpInboundDirectory);
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store(), "*.json"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5000));
    return pollerMetadata;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(localDirectory);
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    source.setMaxFetchSize(1);
    return source;
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(this.sftpMessageSource()).channel(fileInputChannel()).
            transform(this::messageTransformer).channel(fileOutputChannel()).
            handle(orderOutMessageHandler()).get();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileOutputChannel")
public SftpMessageHandler orderOutMessageHandler() {
    SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    LOGGER.debug(" Creating SFTP MessageHandler - Start ");
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(sftpOutboundDirectory));
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {
        @Override
        public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
            if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {

                return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected Input is File.");
            }
        }
    });
    LOGGER.debug(" Creating SFTP MessageHandler - End ");
    return handler;
}

@Bean
@org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel", outputChannel = "fileOutputChannel")
public Transformer messageTransformer() {
    return message -> {
        File file=orderTransformer.transformInboundMessage(message);
        return (Message<?>) file;
    };
}


@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore store() {
    return new SimpleMetadataStore(hazelcastInstance().getMap("idempotentReceiverMetadataStore"));
}


@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(new Config().setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to be injected into the SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter. This one has to be supplied with a `MetadataStore` based on the shared database.

See more info in the docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#metadata-store

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for reply. So adding  SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter to local filter is enough? in my case there is no database, just a springboot app on multiple hosts.  for MetadataStore should i write any custom code here?

Comment: No, this filter is for remote, for `LsEntry`. I don't think you need filter for local copies. Well, without shared database between your app instances in cluster there is no other way to prevent duplicated on different hosts.

Comment: ok. can i use hazelcast in this use case? if yes, is there any examples, i can refer?

Comment: See this test: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/d21e8f03499c93939b0a618ce96a026eef940ca2/spring-integration-jmx/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/monitor/IdempotentReceiverIntegrationTests.java#L251

Comment: Hi Artem, i added code snippet in above edit. so i added transactionInterceptor, idempotentReceiverInterceptor, store in transfomer and i am getting Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.messaging.Message' in your configuration. while starting app

Comment: No, I didn't mean to add an `IdempotentReceiver` into your config. You should use an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` for your `sftpMessageSource` based on the `SimpleMetadataStore` injected with the `hazelcastInstance().getMap()`

Comment: ok. i added SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter in sftpMessageSource(edited code snippet with latest code) but confused where do i store message headers in hazelcast. in integration flow. do i need to add any custom code to store? And do i need to add any filter after from in integration flow

Comment: Your question was about to not duplicate files on instances. That filter does that for you. Not sure why your question is now about some headers. Different story?..

Comment: apologize for many questions. so just having SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with SimpleMetadataStore injected with the hazelcastInstance().getMap() does the trick here? i was thinking about how sftpmessageSource knows the particular was already processed if i dont have any code to store message data in hazelcast. Does spring integration do that check in back end? Also what does hazelcastInstance().getMap() do here?

Comment: First question is answered in the docs I've mentioned in my answer. Second question is fully related to Hazelcast: I support since you have asked about Hazelcast you should be familiar with it and what its `getMap()` does. I should give us a distributed object as a `Map` implementation - exactl what we need for our use-case. So, all the instances of your application will consult the same distributed `Map. Therefore no duplicates over the cluster. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: you are right. no duplicates over the cluster. but in my integrationflow(in code snippet) where should i do put operation in hazelcast?             here are the dependencies i am using spring-boot.version-2.2.2 maven-spring-integration-sftp-5.1.6.RELEASE hazelcast.version-3.12. Do i  need to use spring-integration-hazelcast here? if yes will i have compatibility issues here?

Comment: No, you don’t need SI-hazelcast for your use-case. The framework does the logic for you. You definitely can have direct access to that distributed map for some reason, but that’s already out of scope the current SO topic

Comment: some reason? dont i need to implement any logic for update the map in hazelcast. i got stuck here created new SO  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361579/spring-integration-with-hazelcast

Comment: ok. do i need define the map name (getMap("integrationmetadatastore"));). 
 in my hazelcast configuration?

Comment: Yes, because this is Hazelcast API. And all the instances should use the same name to really get access to the same distributed map